# Wiremock testing with Dynamic HEADERS

Tags: json, spring-boot, junit, junit4, wiremock

I have one wiremock test case which is being used for integration testing. Everything is good but I am stuck at place where I am generating `HttpHeaders` dynamically i.e. `timestamp` etc.
Since I have to mention some dummy values in `JSON` File(like below). 
Can you please help me putting something there which will pass any string that is being generated in my code dynamically.

```
{
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "<SOME_URL>",
    "headers" : {
      "signature" : {
        "contains" : "some dynamically string"
      },
      "timestamp": {
        "contains" : "dynamic timestamp"
      },
      "traceid" : {
        "contains" :"dynamic alpha numeric string"
      }
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "jsonBody": {
        //Some response
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replaced my JSON with below REGEXs

```
"headers" : {
  "signature" : {
    "matches" : ".*some-always-present-chars.*"
  },
  "timestamp": {
    "matches" : "2.*"
  },
  "traceid" : {
    "matches" :".*"
  }
}
```